# Прочитать содержимое doc файла

Tags: c#, doc, файлы

Необходимо прочитать содержимое doc файла, не только текст но и таблицы (на саму таблицу все равно, но разные ячейки - разные данные). Для теста попробовал с помощью COM либы от microsoft. Все хорошо, НО на сервер такое нельзя... Надо отдельную либу, находил упоминания о NPOI но не нашел нормального примера.

Comment: сочувствую!

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358826.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Я так понял, что OpenXML работает только с файлами 2007 версии офиса и свежее? (docx, xlsx ...)??

Comment: @zuev93, честно говоря, не в курсе насчет более ранних версий офиса. а оно (поддержка этих самых более ранних версий) вам надо? из всех кого я знаю буквально у пары людей 2007, у абсолютного большинства 10, ну и 13 есть у нескольких.

Comment: К сожалению надо, обработка doc'ов должна быть на сервере, а эти самые доки - приходят из стороннего апи...

Comment: @zuev93: а что ж вы хотели? `.doc` и `.docx` — это два совершенно разных формата, даже `.doc`, созданные разными версиями офиса, разные. Одной библиотекой прочитать всё было бы, конечно, круто, н вряд ли получится.

Comment: OpenXML не работает с doc-файлами.

Answer (score 0):

[Работа с Com сервером Word](http://wladm.narod.ru/C_Sharp/comword.html)